# Finding Binary heap node's position after insertion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, binary-heap

Assuming I want to insert a node into a binary heap, how can i find the index of 
the node in the heap after the insertion and the heapifying?
The binary heap is represented as an array.
I need to find this algorithm in O(log(log(n)).

I know how to find it in log n complexity but does not succeed to find it in log log n.

Thank you all.

Comment: Knowing the final position does not reduce the number of moves needed. Needing but O(log(log(n)) comparisons helps if comparisons are costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at how a node is usually inserted. It is appended to the end of the array and then it is swapped with its parent until it reaches the root or becomes greater then or equal to its parent(I assume that we have a min-heap). That's why we just have to find a position of this element in the path from it to the root. But this path is sorted(due to the properties of a heap). That's why we can use binary search to find its position in this path. The length of the path is `O(log n)`, so the binary search works in `O(log(log n))`.

Comment: and how can i do the binary search on the path? If I copy these nodes to a new array and than doing the binary search , the copying will take log n time. So, I assume we won't copy them. In this case, how can i do the binary search only on these specific nodes?

Comment: @BKTomer There is no need to copy them to an array. All what we need is  just an index of the ancestor of this node at a given height(it should be something like n / 2^k).

Comment: Why not obtain O(1) time by returning the node index from the Insert() method? That's even better than *log log N*

Comment: @PieterGeerkens What exactly do you mean? We can't call insert because it would be O(log N).

Comment: @user2040251: Uh? OP's question is " how can i find the index of the node in the heap after the insertion and the heapifying?" I am suggesting simply returning the final index of the just inserted node from Heapify and then from Insert.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I understand it as: what would the index of a new node be if it were inserted and heapfied.

Comment: @user2040251 So how can I do the binary search? I mean , I know the right indices and the path, but given the full array, how should I split the path in every step?

Comment: @BKTomer It is a binary search over the distance from the new node to its ancestor. Initially, the values are left = 1(a parent) and right = height of the heap(the root). Then you split it according to the result of the comparison.